# Corona swipe direction

Tags: lua, game-physics, coronasdk

I am working on a game using Corona sdk. I need to determine a swipe direction, so I can make a body object jump in that direction. I am using Runtime:addEventListener("touch", moveCat) which calls a function moveCat which moves the body object. It is working, but the object moves in the wrong direction. When I swipe up and left, it jumps up and right. Inside the moveCat function I am using cat:applyLinearImpulse( 50, 150, event.x, event.y ) to move the object.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably help if you posted specific code, but in general, for swipes, I store the starting (x1,y1) coordinates and compare them to the ending (x2,y2) coordinates. If x2>x1 then the user swiped from left to right.

Comment: OK, I have determined x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates based on the event.phase began and ended. How do I apply this to applyLinearImpulse() to make the body moves in the desired direction? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I haven't used applyLinearImpulse, but does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006550/how-do-i-use-applylinearimpulse-based-on-rotation-in-corona-lua https://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/02/16/quick-applylinearimpulse-question